# Fix required for VWAP Plotting issues in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have coded the VWAP indicator, Though it's functional but it's giving some plotting anomaly at the end of the session of the last trading session. My code is as follows -

```
//@version=5
indicator(title = "Volume Weighted Average Price", shorttitle = "VWAP", overlay = true, precision=3)

PlotB1 = input(true, title="Plot VWAP StDev Band 1")
PlotB2 = input(true, title="Plot VWAP StDev Band 2")
PlotB3 = input(true, title="Plot VWAP StDev Band 3")

//Calcul For Opening Range
bartimeSess = time('D')
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]
isessp = session.regular
tp = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session=isessp)
day = request.security(tp, "D", time, barmerge.gaps_off)
newSession = ta.change(day) ? 1 : 0
[vwap, upper1, lower1] = ta.vwap(hlc3, newSession, 1.0)
[vwap2, upper2, lower2] = ta.vwap(hlc3, newSession, 2.0)
[vwap3, upper3, lower3] = ta.vwap(hlc3, newSession, 3.0)

plot(vwap, color = color.fuchsia, linewidth = 2)
plot(PlotB1 ? upper1 : na, color = color.navy, linewidth = 1)
plot(PlotB1 ? lower1 : na, color = color.navy, linewidth = 1)
plot(PlotB2 ? upper2 : na, color = color.blue, linewidth = 1)
plot(PlotB2 ? lower2 : na, color = color.blue, linewidth = 1)
plot(PlotB3 ? upper3 : na, color = color.aqua, linewidth = 1)
plot(PlotB3 ? lower3 : na, color = color.aqua, linewidth = 1)
```

[image]

You can see the issue highlighted by the circle on the chart. How Can I fix this? Regards.

I have tried color related coding within my very little knowledge but could not fix it. Looking for the expertise and the code necessary to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot connects all values of the series, to avoid the expected "anomaly", you can assign a transparent color after the `newSession` event:

```
plot(PlotB1 ? upper1 : na, color = newSession ? color(na) : color.navy, linewidth = 1)
```

[image]